# Replacing the particular symbol in a div depending on input

Tags: jquery

I have this div with credit card information divided in 4 groups:

```
<div class="card-number"> 
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number1">****</div>
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number2">****</div>
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number3">****</div>
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number4">****</div>
</div>
```

and this input which is collecting user's credit card number:

```
<input type="text" id="cc_number" name="cc_number" required=""/>
```

I've made so far this:

```
$("#cc_number").on('keyup', function() {
    var number = $(this).val();

    var parts = [];    
    for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i += 4) {
        parts.push(number.substring(i, i + 4));
    }    
    
    if($(this).val() == "") {
        
    } else {
        if(parts[0].lenght == 4) {
            $("#cc_display_number1").text(parts[0]);
        }
        if(parts[1].lenght == 4) {
            $("#cc_display_number2").text(parts[1]);
        }
        if(parts[2].lenght == 4) {
            $("#cc_display_number3").text(parts[2]);
        }
        if(parts[3].lenght == 4) {
            $("#cc_display_number4").text(parts[3]);
        }
    }
});
```

but it's not working as expected. I want for each digit inputted in the field to replace the particular `*` in the `card-number` class div. Any ideas?

```js
$("#cc_number").on('keyup', function() {
    var number = $(this).val();

    var parts = [];    
    for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i += 4) {
        parts.push(number.substring(i, i + 4));
    }    
    if($(this).val() == "") {
        
    } else {
        if(parts[0].lenght == 4) {
            $("#cc_display_number1").text(parts[0]);
        }
        if(parts[1].lenght == 4) {
            $("#cc_display_number2").text(parts[1]);
        }
        if(parts[2].lenght == 4) {
            $("#cc_display_number3").text(parts[2]);
        }
        if(parts[3].lenght == 4) {
            $("#cc_display_number4").text(parts[3]);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-number"> 
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number1">****</div>
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number2">****</div>
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number3">****</div>
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number4">****</div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="cc_number" name="cc_number" required=""/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the errors in your console - until the user enters enough characters, your `parts` array won't have four elements, so checking `parts[1].length` will fail, even if you correct the typo.

You also need to pad the parts, in case the user hasn't entered a full four characters yet.

```js
$("#cc_number").on('keyup', function() {
    var number = $(this).val();

    var parts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i += 4) {
        parts.push(number.substring(i, i + 4).padEnd(4, "*"));
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
      $("#cc_display_number" + (i + 1)).text(parts[i]);
    }
    
    for (var i = parts.length; i < 4; i++) {
      $("#cc_display_number" + (i + 1)).text("****");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-number"> 
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number1">****</div>
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number2">****</div>
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number3">****</div>
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number4">****</div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="cc_number" name="cc_number" required=""/>
```

Comment: Absolutely what I asked for. The only problem is when you fast type and fast delete the card number the script is bugging and not replacing with `*`. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I've added an extra loop to reset the elements beyond what the user has typed in. Other than that, I can't type fast enough to break it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to test if `parts` array have index like:

```js
$("#cc_number").on('keyup', function() {
    var number = $(this).val();
    var parts = [];    
    for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i += 4) {
        parts.push(number.substring(i, i + 4));
    }    
    if($(this).val() == "") {
        
    } else {
        if(parts[0] && parts[0].length == 4) {
            $("#cc_display_number1").text(parts[0]);
        }
        if(parts[1] && parts[1].length == 4) {
            $("#cc_display_number2").text(parts[1]);
        }
        if(parts[2] && parts[2].length == 4) {
            $("#cc_display_number3").text(parts[2]);
        }
        if(parts[3] && parts[3].length == 4) {
            $("#cc_display_number4").text(parts[3]);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-number"> 
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number1">****</div>
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number2">****</div>
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number3">****</div>
     <div class="section" id="cc_display_number4">****</div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="cc_number" name="cc_number" required=""/>
```